# I have Calendar date, How can I bring closing in each date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014

I have Calendar date between '2020-01-01' And '2020-01-03'. How can I bring Sum of qty till each date without using union, I have tried the below query:

```
SELECT 
    Date,
    Sum(ILE.Quantity)
FROM 
    Calender C 
LEFT JOIN 
    [XYZ$Item Ledger Entry] ILE 
ON 
    C.Date <= Cast(ILE.[Posting Date] as Date )
WHERE 
    Date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-03'
GROUP BY 
    Date;
```

[image: This is queried Data]

**I want my result to look like below**

```
Date           Qty
01-01-2020  24550318.91
01-02-2020  24321291.58
01-03-2020  24526795.94
```

`Select Date from Calendar C  Where Date Between '2020-01-01'And '2020-01-03'`

```
Select '2020-01-01'[Qty Till],Sum(ILE.Quantity)From[XYZ$Item Ledger Entry]ILE Where [Posting Date] <= '2020-01-01'
Select '2020-01-03'[Qty Till],Sum(ILE.Quantity) From[XYZ$Item Ledger Entry]ILE Where [Posting Date] <= '2020-01-02'
Select '2020-01-03'[Qty Till],Sum(ILE.Quantity) From[XYZ$Item Ledger Entry]ILE Where [Posting Date] <= '2020-01-03'
```

Comment: Request you to share input and expected output dataset. That way, the community would be able to answer your question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should work, but I believe your condition might be the other way around. The following will only consider entries that are ***past*** those 3 days:

```
C.Date <= Cast(ILE.[Posting Date] as Date)
```

If you want records ***previous to*** those dates, then you need to switch it:

```
Cast(ILE.[Posting Date] as Date) <= C.Date
```

---

If you want to speed up the query, create an index on `[Posting Date]` column:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCI_LedgerEntry_PostingDate ON [XYZ$Item Ledger Entry] ([Posting Date])
```

And then avoid casting the value to date on the comparison (although the engine might still use the index, not sure though):

```
ILE.[Posting Date] < DATEADD(DAY, 1, C.Date)
```

Comment: Hi Is there way to execute this query faster